# Can I touch voltage?

Tags: capacitor, ac, dc, pwm, frequency

After watched this man [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZxBF7WC0TQk) man, I have some questions.

1. He touched 170 VDC, what is max DC voltage can I touch when I dry? And wet?
2. What is max AC voltage can I touch when I dry? And wet?
3. Is using 'diode bridge' convert dangerous 50 VAC voltage to safe DC voltage?
4. 120 VAC @ 60 Hz vs 120 VAC @ 100 MHz, high or low frequency make voltage dangerous?
5. Is '50 V PWM 60 Hz' dangerous like AC or safe like DC?
6. Can I touch charged capacitor (only one leg)?

Comment: As a fair warning, you may find some of the answers have an angry tone of voice.  Questions in the form of "how close can I get to this life-threatening situation" lend themselves to people pointing out that the best answer is "don't."  That can be done in a rather loud manner.

Comment: Every question depends on resistance ( wet or dry) and if current flows thru your feet to hand via heart, or tongue or just across finger .  A fresh 9V battery on your tongue stings but on your finger is not noticed. Although <50V is considered "safe Low voltage" but dont but across your tongue.  High frequency (MHz) makes skin a better conductor rather than a insulator

Comment: imho, the most interesting question is the one about PWM compared to sinusoidal voltage. If  there's a difference,  it would have to do with the "frequency response" of your skin I would guess.

Comment: I've seen this guy plenty times on YouTube. He's (ironically) a very intelligent person. Mehdi Sadaghdar does have a Master's in Electrical Engineering so I'm extremely certain he knows what he's doing. Just because you see someone do it, doesn't mean you should automatically make assumptions and say, "Hey, I should try that." Which brings us this question. Why do you want to do what Mr. Sadaghbar does? He seems to be very knowledgeable, as shown in this video. You _can_ touch anything you want but it shouldn't be in your best interest.

Comment: Just for giggles, UL (USA) puts a limit of 48 VDC or 36 VAC on exposed conductors, such as the battery terminals in your car or a 48 VDC golf cart. This can create very mild pain, but ever time you double the voltage, the power through your skin goes up 4 times. I know a guy who accidentally grabbed the phase A and C bus bars on a surge protector under test at 600 VAC. He survived by the grace of Angels but has terrible burn marks in each palm, the same width as the 1-1/4" bus bars.

Comment: @Sparky256, if I remember correctly, that limit applies to dry locations. The limit is lower for damp locations.

Comment: _"safe DC voltage"_ Incorrect assumption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AC and DC are both dangerous.

Its more common to be hurt by AC because DC generally does not go beyond 15V in domestic devices while AC can have values around 120V or 240V.

We are less tolerant to AC as you can see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=trmxzUVT2eE)

The main reason seems to be related with the capacitive effect of the skin.

Comment: From the video I concluded: 1- 60VDC is safe but pain. 2- 20VAC is safe but pain. 3- 'diode bridge' Convert dangerous 20 VAC voltage to safe DC voltage.

Comment: Your video say 60VDC is pain, and my video say 120VDC is safe and not pain, who is right?

Comment: Both are right! it depends of the person's pain tolerance.

Comment: "person's pain tolerance", but it is huge deference between 60v and 120v ! , Any way can i test it my self by increase volt until feel pain ?

Comment: Mehdi Sadaghdar has a very high tolerance to pain. He know exactly what he is doing( Medhi is an electrical engineer). Be careful  with electrical shocks if you don't have enough experience don't do the test.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend reading [this page](https://www.physics.ohio-state.edu/%7Ep616/safety/fatal_current.html).  It discusses the question of what is a fatal current versus what is not.  It does a decent enough job at being precise.

Myself, my recommendation to these questions would be "don't."  Don't push the limits.  More formally, my advice would be do not trust your life to something some stranger said on the internet.  The day you no longer need to ask someone whether it is dangerous or not is the first day were it might be okay to touch these things, because you will be fully aware of what is happening.

As for the remainder of the questions, some of them are simply answered by applying the knowledge of how dangerous a given current amount is.  However, there are two small details worth knowing.

The first is that we are more susceptible to ventricular fibrillation from AC shocks.  30mA of AC is enough to induce fibrillation, while it may take up to 500mA with DC.  The mechanisms governing this are [not yet fully understood](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/14686589), so I would avoid giving advice on whether the 100MHz signal is more lethal or not.  However, I would point out that there is something called the "skin effect," where current tends to travel along the outer surface of a conductor at high frequencies.  In this case, that would be quite far from the heart.

The second key thing to know is that wall-socket AC oscillates faster than your muscles can relax.  This means that if you grab something that electrocutes you with AC, there is a decent chance that your hand will clamp down on that object, preventing you from letting go.  I have heard stories of people being knocked away from their predicament by a friend and a good hard hit with a 2x4!

As for the capacitor, touching one side of a charged object is *rarely* fatal.  You have to touch both sides to complete the circuit and discharge the current.  If you only touch one side, it becomes an electrostatics problem, where electrons shift into your body to balance the charges out.

As it would happen, we deal with charges like this constantly.  If you've ever shocked yourself after walking on carpet, that's a Electrostatic Discharge (ESD) of 30,000V or more!  So generally speaking touching one side is safe.

However, if there's a lesson you should learn from that video, it's that when you're touching one side of a dangerous power source, it is frustratingly easy to accidentally touch the other side, completing the circuit.  If you talk to mechanics, one of the first things they do before working on a car is remove their wedding ring.  It's too easy to accidentally complete a circuit with your ring, and that ring will get hot *fast*!

Comment: Wedding ring, there are cases of people amputating a finger due to shorting 24v truck batteries...

Answer (score 0):

IEC power supply standards say that after X volt (DC), you need to ensure wire sheaths are sufficient. That voltage is something like 30 V, but look it up yourself.

If you absolutely must touch voltage, then use the human body model for leakage current. The body is a 1 kohm resistor, and you need to keep the current through your heart under X milliamps. I think x is 0.1 mA, but don't quote me.

Also, you can still burn skin without having current flow through your heart.

Comment: _"but look it up yourself"_, _"I think x is"_. This is very vague and boarderline does not answer the question. Can you re-write your answer?